# What fraction of stellar systems could/can Kepler and TESS search for planets?

Tags: exoplanet, kepler-telescope, tess

Since Kepler and TESS search for exoplanets by their transit in front of their host stars, they can only find planets around stars whose ecliptic plane is nearly edge-on as seen from Earth. (Ref 1 & 2)  I searched the web for what fraction of stellar systems that was--without success.  I also searched all the questions containing "Kepler" on this site, also with no success.  So I decided to calculate it myself using our solar system as a reference.  To detect a planet at Jupiter's distance from the Sun, the maximum tilt angle would be arctan(Sun's radius/Jupiter's orbital radius) = 0.052 degrees, where the Sun's radius = 6.96E5 km and Jupiter's orbital radius = 7.79E8 km. (Ref 3).  Given a 90 degree range from edge-on to pole-on, 0.052 degrees corresponds to 0.058%, or less than 1 part in 1700.  Doing the same caculation, but only out to Mars, I get 0.19%, or a little less than 1 part in 500.  Since this is a much smaller fraction than I expected, I wonder if I made a mistake.  Does anyone know of a reference that gives an official answer to this question for either Kepler or TESS?

Kepler Mission: 
https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/kepler/main/index.html

TESS Mission:
https://www.nasa.gov/content/about-tess

Sun and Jupiter data: 
https://www.wikipedia.org/

Comment: Googling "kepler number of target stars" gives pretty quick results... You can't estimate the number of stars by those geometrical arguments, because you have to take into account where Kepler was looking, what luminosities are visible there in which numbers. Same for Tess.

Comment: This is probably on-topic here but it's possible it might be answered much more quickly  in [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) since it has more to do with the nature and statistics of exoplanet systems than the operation of these spacecraft.

Comment: Vince 49, Check page 6 in this pdf https://trs.jpl.nasa.gov/bitstream/handle/2014/42818/12-2809_A1b.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y It discusses the probability calculation but doesn't give an answer.

Comment: @Organic Marble, thanks.  The .pdf does give an approximate answer for the 1 AU case of about 0.5%.  Using more precise data, I got about 0.3%.  I'm not sure if the difference is due to their approximation or an error in my calculation, so I hope to get a definitive answer.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape, I'm only interested in the limits of the missions' transit measuring method, not in factors related to the properties of exoplanets themselves, such as luminosity, size, etc.

Comment: @uhoh, please see my comment to AtmosphericPrisonEscape.  I believe the limit of particular exoplanet detection techniques, planetary coronagraphs, starshades, etc. are on-topic and I'm more likely to get an answer here--we'll see.  :)

Comment: These measurements are limited by noise, sampling plan and cadence, but those are linked directly to luminosity and size of star, size of exoplanet and its orbit. I don't see how they can be separated. Anyway good luck!